# Is there a way to make an API request and only get data that will meet certain criteria prior to making the request?

Tags: javascript, reactjs, api, axios

Right now, my code makes a request to a movie API every time the user clicks a button. Part of the request involves randomizing the movie's id on the request so that the response.data is a random movie. However, there are hundreds of thousands of movies/tv shows/episodes in this API so I'd like to narrow them to only the ones that have imdb ratings and posters. Right now, this is what my code looks like:

```
  function randomizeMovie() {
    axios({
      "method": "GET",
      "url": `http://www.omdbapi.com/?i=${randomMovieId}&apikey={apikey}`
    })
      .then((response) => {
      displayMovieTitle(response.data.Title)
      displayMoviePoster(response.data.Poster)
    })
    .catch((err) => {
      console.log(err, "error")
    })
  }
```

I tried doing the following and though it kinda worked (I say kinda cause it would randomize on my console but wouldn't show the change on frontend), there's a limit of 1,000 API requests per day and this definitely consumed all of them

```
  function randomizeMovie() {
    axios({
      "method": "GET",
      "url": `http://www.omdbapi.com/?i=${randomMovieId}&apikey={apikey}`
    })
      .then((response) => {
        response.data.imdbRating === "N/A" ? randomizeMovie() : 
      displayMovieTitle(response.data.Title)
      displayMoviePoster(response.data.Poster)
    })
    .catch((err) => {
      console.log(err, "error")
    })
  }
```

So my question is: can I set conditions for the API response to meet without making a request call? Or is there any other solution that I can't think of? I've read a lot of stack overflow questions, reddit, google, all of it and I can't find a solution. Any help is appreciated!

Answer (score 1):

http://www.omdbapi.com/ Which says it has parameters options. os you can use that to search for movies by changing the year or search keyword. changing params is a good way to get more random movies.
Use random functions for parameters

Comment: So for this app, there's no search entry. What happens is that onClick of a button, a movie/tv show/episode is randomized and displayed. Long story short, I don't think I can solve this problem the way I thought but I found a solution, if anyone cares to know what it is, I'm getting Netflix data through koggle. Will randomize that data onClick and then display the poster, title, cast, etc through omdb api! :-) Thank you for your response

Comment: You can use the time of onclick as well to do the randomness. you can use the second at which the click is done to randomise the result